# How to redirect/block old URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/$ views/sessions/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ views/sessions/$1.php [L]
.... (a dozen line of rewriting)
```

The links on my site work like this:

`mysite.com/login/` to access `mysite.com/views/sessions/login.php`

But now I want to block access to old links.
When the user goes to `mysite.com/views/sessions/login.php` it returns a 404 error or returns it directly to the link `mysite.com/login/`

How to block old URLs?

I added [R=301,NC,L] (`RewriteRule ^login/$ views/sessions/login.php [R=301,NC,L]`)

but when I want to access to `mysite.com/views/sessions/login.php`

I have this error :  **"Forbidden You don't have permission to access /C:/wamp/www/mysite/views/sessions/login.php on this server."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one query string parameter while rewriting url, see the below code. I have added one query string parameter for redirecting the url.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ views/sessions/$1.php?s=old [L]
```

**To redirect old urls :** (old urls will be redirected to new urls)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?s=old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ $1/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

**To block the old urls :** (old urls will be blocked)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?s=old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ $1/ [R=401,NC,L]
```

**Edit:** (adding query string to new urls)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ views/sessions/$1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&s=old [L]
```

> `&s=old` is not compulsory, its just to apply condition for blocking the old urls. you can take any variable instead of it, choose it as it does not affect to your program logic.

Comment: I do not understand, I'm just trying to block access to page like ``views/sessions/$1.php`` because the new access is ``([a-zA-Z]+)/``

Comment: please check my updated answer, you can block the old by changing the http status code to 401 Unauthorized or 404 Not Found  (as per your requirement).

Comment: Thank you ! It work at litle ready but all my url with GET for example ``/login/?status=error`` don't work
And why I must to add ``?s=old`` ? (thank you for your help)

Comment: My .htaccess looks like ``Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ views/sessions/$1.php?s=old [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?s=old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ $1/ [R=302,NC,L]``

Comment: you need to add `%{QUERY_STRING}` for it, check updated answer.

Comment: I will never have found this alone, thank you very much
so I must proceed in the same way for all my redirects? (for example for ``/views/account/index.php`` or ``/profile/count/index.php``)

Comment: I can't add a subfolder, I have 404 error, can you tell me why ? ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/account/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)/$ views/account/$1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&s=old [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^account/(.*&)?s=old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^views/account/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ $1/ [R=302,NC,L]``

Comment: you can do the same way as for the sessions or you can write rules for  it dynamically.

Comment: Thank for your help but I have a problem with this code so I created a new question, if you can help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020245/how-to-create-a-folder-with-url-rewriting